# How do I open my Windows terminal settings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, windows-terminal

I have Visual Studio and Windows Terminal installed in my PC. When I click the tab drop down and select Settings, the settings.json (Alt+click Settings for defaults.json) opens in Notepad. How do I configure to open the files in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 3):

When you edit Windows Terminal settings (Ctrl+Alt+comma, by default) it loads the JSON file using whatever editor is configured to edit JSON files, system-wide.

One way to change that is to open File Explorer, navigate to (or create) a JSON file, then right click on it and look for "Open with..." then "Choose another app".

Pick VS Code and select "Always use this app to open .json files".